# What are the correct specs for an SNES power supply?

Tags: hardware, snes

I bought an SNES recently, and it came with a aftermarket power supply. Is this one at the correct amperage, etc.?

[image: Input: AC 120V 60Hz; Output: DC9V - 850mA]

Comment: 10V at 850mA is 8.5W. 9V at 850mA is 7.65W. If any game or whatever you run on the NES that requires more than 7.65W you'll (maybe, probably, or maybe not) experience a failure. This means that the NES is working hard - think games that use the NES CPU and RAM (etc.) a lot. However, it's likely that's it's ok for most games. Also, specs usually include some buffer and will likely work over the rated spec. Or not, it might catch on fire, burn your house down, and kill your spouse. Depends on quality and manufacturer.

Comment: @Steve: You're assuming a switching power supply that will draw constant *power* from an input of varying voltage.  As Hearth pointed out, a 1991 design likely used linear regulators and would draw constant *current* of any voltage sufficiently above 5 volts (but not so high that it overheats the regulators.)

Comment: "You can't use any old 9v supply you've got lying around the house because the SNES uses a **center negative pin** which is the opposite of the de facto standard today. Best case is simply nothing happens, worst case it bricks your SNES. A 3rd party adaptor that's advertised for SNES is not likely to break your SNES, but you might have weird visual artifacts or other glitches." [reddit : is_9_volts_enough_to_power_the_snes](https://www.reddit.com/r/snes/comments/3mgzwy/is_9_volts_enough_to_power_the_snes/)

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah ... It regulates it to a constant 5 volts. Any headroom anove that goes to power supply current capability, which is determined by the needs of the device being powered .. until it can't provide any more, then undesirable things happen. I too am an electrical engineer, and my comment does not disagree with that answer.

Comment: The linear regulators don't draw constant current. They provide a constant 5v, the current changes depending on the load ... Idle sleep loop? Low power. Lots of graphics and sound processing work a coprocessor in the cartridge? More current. Regardless of supply. 5v , always. Well ... Technically when you overload the supply, the voltage will also likely drop below the rated voltage. I think your understanding of voltage and current regulation isn't fully correct. The entire point of a voltage regulator is to regulate voltage, one of the three parts of ohms law.

Comment: It is possible to have a supply that is constant current, and the voltage is allows to do whatever is necessary to maintain that constant current flow. But this has limits ... The supply can only go up to a certain voltage (whatever the design was) and when it hits that limit, the amount of current will drop and no longer be constant. This is called compliance voltage. I don't think I've ever seen this as a power supply for a device, though ... It's usually used for individual circuits.

Comment: Anyway, I'm not assuming a thing. This is how things work, period.

Comment: There's a voltage and a current listed on the NES. Ohms law states that it implies also a power rating, voltage times current equals power. If you tinker with either, the combo may be enough for the circuit being powered if the power rating is above the power rating of the original supply. That's my whole point. We don't know the level of margin the designers built in, only whats on the label. This describes how that works, with the caveats of "you should TRY to match the voltage, but if you get close, at least try to exceed the power rating"

Comment: Even if you have a supply with a bit higher voltage or a bit lower voltage but the power rating is the same, you may experience differences due simply to efficiency of the supply. I.e. it maybe harder for it to use that different voltage, effectively causing the NES to have less power available.

Comment: @Steve: I was talking about varying the supply voltage while holding the regulated power constant, e.g. at its peak.  And since its regulated to presumably 5V, that means constant current in the regulated side, for the peak load.  I agree "constant" doesn't clearly and unambiguously describe what I meant.

Comment: @Steve: But anyway, for any given actual load, the current @ 10V matches the current in the 5V regulated supply 1:1.  So a lower supply voltage lowers the power dissipated by the linear regulator, down to any voltage above maybe 7V (a 5V linear  regulator has some minimum "dropout", the least voltage it can drop across itself).  What matters is the current rating on the wall wart, not total power.  A linear regulator just throws away 
voltage above 5V, unlike modern switching regulators which convert energy nearly 1:1. That's why linear regulators are rarely used these days.

Comment: @Steve: As  [pipe commented](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/397853/what-are-the-correct-specs-for-an-snes-power-supply#comment558777_397856), it turns out that the SNES doesn't only use a 5V regulated supply, it also filters but doesn't regulate a supply voltage for some analog audio stuff.  So there is a reason to aim for close to the nominal supply voltage.  (And an explanation for why it's so much higher than 5V, leading to wasting half the input power that's headed for the digital side: they wanted a ~9V supply as well, but could do without regulation for it.)

Comment: Power and voltage are not the same. Power and current are not the same. Power is the product of voltage and current. You're statement are wrong.

Comment: Holding the voltage constant does not make a constant current supply. The load changes over time, therefore so does the current.

Comment: @Steve What Peter is saying is that the current drawn from the input to a linear regulator is independent of the input voltage. Not that it's independent of the load.

Answer (score 20):

I just went and checked the power supply on my SNES (an original Nintendo power supply)--it's 10 V at 850 mA. Your supply is slightly lower voltage.

Speaking as an electrical engineer with some familiarity with how circuits were designed in the 80s and 90s, it's very probable that 9 V is enough. (current rating doesn't matter as long as it's high enough, by the way--the power supply could be rated to 10,000 A and it would work just fine. Though I'd question why you're using such expensive specialist lab equipment to power an SNES, if it was!)

Most of the SNES (and most 80s and 90s electronics) runs on 5 V, and there's an internal voltage regulator (most likely a linear regulator) that drops the input voltage down to 5 V. There may be some parts of it that run on 9 V (another standard voltage) as well, but that seems unlikely to me--the voltage regulators readily available at the time would typically require at least about 11 V to output a stable 9 V, and while ones that could drop 10 V to 9 V existed, they wouldn't have been as cheap as just using a higher voltage power supply.

It's also possible that some nominally 9 V parts are being run at 10 V straight from the supply; some things are perfectly happy on a pretty wide range of voltages. In that case, your 9 V supply would also be perfectly fine.

In any case, I wouldn't worry about it. Even if it turns out not to work, it's *extremely* rare for something to break from applying too *low* of a voltage. Too high a voltage can cause damage easily, but it takes some weird edge cases for too low a voltage to do any damage at all.

---

Do be aware, however, that low-quality power supplies can fail in ways that *will* damage things. If the power supply is working properly, everything's fine, but if it breaks, in the worst case you could end up passing mains voltage through to your SNES, which absolutely will fry just about everything on the board. Might be a good idea to replace it with one that's a little better quality; there are aftermarket ones out there that look a lot less sketchy than this one.

Comment: Looked at the [schematics](https://wiki.superfamicom.org/uploads/snes_schematic_monochrome.pdf) and they _do_ create a filtered 9V from the 10V, which will now be 8V. This is used for the audio OP-amps and buffers in the lower right section, and there's still enough headroom with 8V. In summary - this answer checks out.

Comment: As someone with knowledge, you could probably improve this answer with a warning about low-quality power supplies. I can't truly tell from the photo, but OP's PSU doesn't strike me as a quality unit.

Comment: @pipe I'm surprised, I would have thought in the early 90s they wouldn't have used 1 V dropout in a design, even if they had a 1 V dropout LDO. But yes, 8 V is still going to be plenty to run the circuitry. It won't be properly filtered, though, since whatever regulator they use will be operating in dropout. That won't cause any problems; you might just have a bit of audio noise.

Comment: @jaskij You have a point. I'll add some.

Comment: @pipe Oh, I see where it's generated (top right of that schematic). It's just filtered, not regulated.

Comment: Current rating *does* matter if you're using an old-fashioned transformer-based power supply rather than a modern switch-mode power supply.  Transformer-based power supplies are unregulated, and the voltage output drops as the current increases.  At near-zero load, a "10000A 9V" power supply could well be putting out 15+ volts.

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you're referring to the NTSC SNES released in 1991, due to the power supply being rated for 120V 60Hz, and due to asking about the SNES and not the Super NES Classic Edition (also known as SNES Mini).

Judging by an image found on an [iFixit article for SNES outer case replacement (NTSC version)](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Super+Nintendo+Super+Nintendo+Outer+Case+Replacement/3870) (click for larger version):

[image: Bottom view of US SNES]

The NTSC SNES is rated for 10V at 850mA. Meanwhile, your power supply outputs 9V at 850mA. While it does have the correct amperage, it is short 1 volt.

Unfortunately, I can't answer whether or not this might cause any problems, and what these problems may be.

Comment: Knowing the technology landscape in 1991, 9V instead of 10V will probably make it only run a bit colder. From the picture, the power supply looks like transformer-based (in 1991 a switching power suppies were neither common nor cheap), so it is at least as unstable as your utility voltage (e.g. +/- 10%) anyway. It may fail to work if the socket voltage is at minimum, but not to the point of breaking.